# Running default AVD for the lowest sdk

Tags: android

My app's min sdk is 2.1 and max sdk - 4.1  , If i run it always starts the emulator for 4.0. Why doenst it run the emulator for the lowest sdk= 2.1 bcos if it works in 2.1 then works in all. How can I make it run the emulator for lowest/min sdk my app is set for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to make the lowest sdk emulator default is to set the SDK min version of your app. Below the emulator sdk verision (as is said), then it will start the lowest sdk emulator.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse go Window -> AVD Manager -> New and set your emulator options, then just run your app on this emulator